# Missing .dll when running pyinstaller .exe file on another computer

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, compilation, pyinstaller

I have been busy making a short script in python to get users HWID. Because computers without python installed can't run the script, I have converted it to an .exe file using pyinstaller.

However, when I tried running the .exe file on my laptop (running windows 7 ultimate and does not have python installed) it gives the error message:

```
The procedure entry point ucrtbase.terminate could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll.
```

Here is how I converted to .exe, just in-case i'm doing it wrong.

Code:

```
import subprocess
import hashlib
import time
def addToClipBoard(text):
    command = 'echo ' + text.strip() + '| clip'
    os.system(command)
x = subprocess.check_output('wmic csproduct get UUID') #gets UUID from pc
x = x[42:] # removes unnecessary parts of string
x = x[:-9] # removes unnecessary parts of string
hash_object = hashlib.sha512(x) # Converts to sha512 hash
hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest() # Converts hash to hex-decimal string
os.system("title HWID tool")
os.system("color 4e")
print("Your protected hardware ID is")
print(hex_dig)
time.sleep(3)
print("This has been automatically saved to your clipboard.") 
addToClipBoard(hex_dig) #saves hex decimal string to clipboard.
```

Than I go into CMD, make sure im in the correct directory and run this.

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile compile.py
```

NOTE: I only get the error when running the .exe file on my laptop. I do not get the error when running on the computer I converted it to an .exe on.

Both the computer I compiled it on, and the laptop are 64bit, windows 7 ultimate machines.

EDIT: Works on my friends computer, however he has python installed.

Can you please tell me why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: The error message isn't very clear. Is the DLL missing entirely, or does it exist but fails to export a symbol? Have you installed all Windows updates on your Windows 7 machine?

Comment: In Windows 7, the CRT API Sets are actual DLLs (in Windows 10 they're virtual), which forward their exported functions to the implementation in ucrtbase.dll. It looks like maybe PyInstaller wasn't smart enough to include ucrtbase.dll, and for some reason your Windows 7 laptop isn't up to date with the Universal CRT update. Microsoft is automatically retrofitting this CRT as an OS component in Windows Vista, 7, and 8 (but not XP).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a missing [Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) as @eryksun alluded to.  However it was published July 10, 2015 so I don't know that it's necessarily an update issue as well.

I had the same problem on a recently installed & updated Windows 7 Professional x64 computer where the compiled .exe did not work (with the `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll` error) prior to installing the redistributable and then did after installing it.